# Exception Value: list indices must be integers, not str

Tags: python, json, parsing

I'm trying to work on a JSON file that I get from an API. But when I try to access it's info once I converted it with `json.loads()`. I get the following error:

```
Exception Value: list indices must be integers, not str
```

the python code :

```
response = requests.get(url, params=params)
print(response.text)    
results= json.loads(response.text)
result = results['results']['lists'] ['id']
```

the JSON output :

```
{"meta":{"pagination":{}},"results":[{"id":"3358","status":"ACTIVE","fax":"","addresses":[],"notes":[],"confirmed":false,"lists":[{"id":"60","status":"ACTIVE"}],"source":"API","email_addresses":[{"id":"d4ae529ce120","status":"ACTIVE","confirm_status":"NO_CONFIRMATION_REQUIRED","opt_in_source":"ACTION_BY_OWNER","opt_in_date":"2015-06-17T16:07:09.000Z","email_address":"test35@tes.com"}],"prefix_name":"","first_name":"test44","middle_name":"","last_name":"","job_title":"","company_name":"test","home_phone":"","work_phone":"","cell_phone":"","custom_fields":[],"created_date":"2015-06-17T16:07:09.000Z","modified_date":"2015-06-17T16:07:09.000Z","source_details":"Site"}]}
```

How can I access the elements with the indices strings or what library do you suggest to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `results` key gives a list of objects:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> import json
>>> pprint(json.loads('''{"meta":{"pagination":{}},"results":[{"id":"3358","status":"ACTIVE","fax":"","addresses":[],"notes":[],"confirmed":false,"lists":[{"id":"60","status":"ACTIVE"}],"source":"API","email_addresses":[{"id":"d4ae529ce120","status":"ACTIVE","confirm_status":"NO_CONFIRMATION_REQUIRED","opt_in_source":"ACTION_BY_OWNER","opt_in_date":"2015-06-17T16:07:09.000Z","email_address":"test35@tes.com"}],"prefix_name":"","first_name":"test44","middle_name":"","last_name":"","job_title":"","company_name":"test","home_phone":"","work_phone":"","cell_phone":"","custom_fields":[],"created_date":"2015-06-17T16:07:09.000Z","modified_date":"2015-06-17T16:07:09.000Z","source_details":"Site"}]}''')
... )
{u'meta': {u'pagination': {}},
 u'results': [{u'addresses': [],
               u'cell_phone': u'',
               u'company_name': u'test',
               u'confirmed': False,
               u'created_date': u'2015-06-17T16:07:09.000Z',
               u'custom_fields': [],
               u'email_addresses': [{u'confirm_status': u'NO_CONFIRMATION_REQUIRED',
                                     u'email_address': u'test35@tes.com',
                                     u'id': u'd4ae529ce120',
                                     u'opt_in_date': u'2015-06-17T16:07:09.000Z',
                                     u'opt_in_source': u'ACTION_BY_OWNER',
                                     u'status': u'ACTIVE'}],
               u'fax': u'',
               u'first_name': u'test44',
               u'home_phone': u'',
               u'id': u'3358',
               u'job_title': u'',
               u'last_name': u'',
               u'lists': [{u'id': u'60', u'status': u'ACTIVE'}],
               u'middle_name': u'',
               u'modified_date': u'2015-06-17T16:07:09.000Z',
               u'notes': [],
               u'prefix_name': u'',
               u'source': u'API',
               u'source_details': u'Site',
               u'status': u'ACTIVE',
               u'work_phone': u''}]}
```

Note the `[...]` square brackets around the `results` value.

You need to use a loop to go over each:

```
for result in results['results']:
    print result['id']
```

or use indexing to address specific entries:

```
print results['result'][0]['id']
```

There is no `'lists'` key.

Note that the `requests` library can handle JSON data natively; no need to use the `json` library here:

```
response = requests.get(url, params=params)
results = response.json()
```